# git show on double click of commit hash in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, git, zsh, iterm2

I am using [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) with [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). `git log --oneline` shows me the git tree:

0b99548e commit A
eb980d4c commit B
e7e5e043 commit C

In order to view a commit, I need to do the following steps:

- double click the commit hash
- open a new tab
- write `git show`
- paste the commit hash and hit enter

Is there a way to view the result of `git show commit-hash` when I just double-click the hash or Command + double click the hash or some other quick way?

Comment: Why do you need to open the new tab?

Comment: @Seth because I want to keep the display of the git tree. But even if I close the view of `git log --oneline`, I still need to write down `git show` and paste the hash.